# React Hooks and memory MERN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

Prodlem with React Hooks (MERN stack)

Suddenly, after trying to add a filter to the page stopped showing objects (although they are definitely there, even new ones are created). For a couple of days of my efforts nothing worked (even tried to roll back the code to the old version, it still does not work).

Home file:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { axiosInstance } from '../helpers/axiosInstance';
import { HideLoading, ShowLoading } from '../redux/alertsSlice';
import { Col, Row, message } from 'antd';
import Bus from '../components/Bus';

function Home() {
  const { user } = useSelector(state => state.users)
  const [filters = {}, setFilters] = useState({});
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [buses, setBuses] = useState([]);

  const getBuses = async () => {
    const tempFilters = {};
    Object.keys(filters).forEach((key) => {
      if (filters[key]) {
        tempFilters[key] = filters[key];
      }
    })
    try {
      dispatch(ShowLoading())
      const response = await axiosInstance.post(
        "/api/buses/get-all-buses",
        tempFilters
      );
      dispatch(HideLoading());
      if (response.data.success) {
        setBuses(response.data.data);
      } else {
        message.error(response.data.message);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(HideLoading());
      message.error(error.message);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getBuses();
    //setSelectedBus();
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <div className='my-3 card p-2'>
        <Row gutter={10}>
          <Col lg={6} sm={24}>
            <input type='text'
              placeholder='From'
              value={filters.from}
              onChange={(e) => setFilters({ ...filters, from: e.target.value })}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col lg={6} sm={24}>
            <input type='text'
              placeholder='To'
              value={filters.to}
              onChange={(e) => setFilters({ ...filters, to: e.target.value })}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col lg={6} sm={24}>
            <input type='date'
              placeholder='Date'
              value={filters.journeyDate}
              onChange={(e) => setFilters({ ...filters, journeyDate: e.target.value })}
            />
          </Col>
          <Col lg={6} sm={24}>
            <button className='primary-btn' onClick={() => getBuses()}>
              Filter
            </button>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Row gutter={[15, 15]}>
          {buses.filter((bus) => bus.status === "Yet to start").map((bus) => (
            <Col lg={12} xs={24} sm={24}>
              <Bus bus={bus} />
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

The busesRoute file (get-all-buses is of main interest there":

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Bus = require("../models/busModel")
const authMiddleware = require("../middlewares/authMiddleware")


// add-bus

router.post('/add-bus', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const existingBus = await Bus.findOne({ number: req.body.number })

        if (existingBus) {
            return res.status(200).send({
                seccess: false,
                meggage: 'Bus already exists',
            })
        }
        const newBus = new Bus(req.body);
        await newBus.save();
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: 'Bus added successfully'
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            meggage: error.message
        })
    }
});

// update-bus

router.post("/update-bus", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Bus.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id, req.body)
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: 'Bus updated successfully',
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({success: false, message: error.meggage})
    }
});

// delete-bus

router.post("/delete-bus", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Bus.findByIdAndDelete(req.body._id, req.body)
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: 'Bus deleted    successfully',
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({success: false, message: error.meggage})
    }
});


// get-all-buses

router.post("/get-all-buses", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const buses = await Bus.find();
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "Buses fetched successfully",
            data: buses,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        })
    };
})


//get-bus-by-id

router.post("/get-bus-by-id", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const bus = await Bus.findById(req.body._id);
        return res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "Buses fetched successfully",
            data: bus,
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: error.message
        })
    };
})




module.exports = router;
```

p.s. Later, I realized that the buses data is just not transferred, and the console got an error for the first attached file: "Line 41:6: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'getBuses'. Either include it or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps " :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUxvA.png

I usd a MobgoDB:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const busSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    number : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    capacity : {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    from : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    to : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    journeyDate : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    departure : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    arrival : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    type : {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    fare : {
        type: Number,
        require: true
    },
    seatsBooked : {
        type: Array,
        default:[]
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Yet to Start',
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('buses', busSchema)
```

Comment: We can't see the data that is in state, but is `filter((bus) => bus.status === "Yet to start")` filtering all the results? What specifically isn't working? It ***looks*** like the endpoint is returning an empty array. Have you investigated your backend? Please [edit] to provide better details on what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is, your `getBuses` method is only called once, when the component is mounted. Your console is asking you to add its reference to the dependency array so that is could be re-run everytime `getBuses` is updated. Try replacing your `useEffect` with the following :

```
useEffect(() => {
    getBuses();
}, [getBuses]) // <-- This is the dependency array, filled with `getBuses`
```

For the same reasons, you may also want to wrap your `getBuses` method with a `useCallback`, which would allow it better handle changed to its dependencies (such as `filters`, for instance).

---

**EDIT 1 :**

The following snippet which you put in your code

```
const tempFilters = {};
Object.keys(filters).forEach((key) => {
  if (filters[key]) {
    tempFilters[key] = filters[key];
  }
})
```

is basically copying each key (and its associated value) from your `filters` object into a new object, without applying any processing. You can therefor get rid of it and directly reference the `filters` object.

Another improvement would be to wrap your `getBuses` method into a `useCallback` with a dependency to `filters`, which would ensure it's always using up-to-date data regarding this `filters` state when making a call to your API.

Also, you can update the `try-catch` call with simple Promises Prototype methods to make the flow more readable (this is just a preference and depends on your coding style)

Here's an example of the updated `getBuses` method :

```
const getBuses = useCallback(async () => {
  dispatch(ShowLoading());
  axiosInstance.post("/api/buses/get-all-buses", tempFilters)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response?.data?.success) {
        setBuses(response.data.data);
      } else {
        message.error(response.data.message);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => message.error(error.message))
    .finally(() => dispatch(HideLoading()));
  }, [filters]);
```

Another improvement would be to create a dynamic onChange handler method for your inputs. You could for instance do the following :

```
const handleOnChange = useCallback(({ target: { name, value } }) => {
  setFilters((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
}, []);
```

and add a `name` attribute to each input, this way you'd just have to pass it `handleOnChange` as the value to the `onChange` props. Here's an example of an updated input :

```html
<input type='text'
  placeholder='From'
  value={filters.from}
  name="from"
  onChange={handleOnChange}
/>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, that helped me. Yes, I would like to know more about what you are talking about

Comment: I redid the getBuses function with useCallback, but the filters still don't work :((

```
const getBuses = useCallback(async () => {
    const tempFilters = {};
    Object.keys(filters).forEach((key) => {
      if (filters[key]) {
        tempFilters[key] = filters[key];
      }
    });
.....
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help !
I've edited my answer to provide additional insight. Let me know if you need help understanding it :)

Comment: oh, thanks a lot, but it still doesn't work. Here's what I have at the moment:
In `get-all-buses` if I write `const buses = await Bus.find(req.body);` the buses will not show up on the main page, but if I write `req.body._id` or `req .body.buses` or `req.body.filters` then everything will work fine.
Also I wrote `console.log(req.body.filters)` before that lowercase and it keeps showing "undefined". I have tried this in a version of everything and your code. Oh, I hate this project...

Comment: Oh, I might have an idea why you've got issue of that kind. Could you please update your post to provide the content of your busModel file and notify me when you did so ? (I suspect you're using an ORM which has a specific kind of parameter structure in its methods that you're not respecting, which would result in this kind of issues)

Comment: I use MongoDB. I updated the post and added the information you need

Comment: If u need somthing else i can add new information

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I believe your issue comes from the way you're calling the mongoose ORM's method. I am not familiar with this ORM, but I guess there could be issues with the format of the parameters you pass to this [find method](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.find()) maybe try to fiddle in this direction ?